# HTML5 video tag in ionic project not working on android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, uiwebview, html5-video

I have an app that was created with ionic v1 a year ago and that's been running well on both iOS and Android. But recently, after an update from Android videos stopped working on some devices like Samsung S6 and LG. I use a simple html video tag in an ion-content and the video is on the web (not local). I can also reproduce the behavior on emulators with latest SDK updates.

I even started a new blank project with ionic 3, added a video tag in the home.html file and had the same issue. The problem shows when deploying on Android devices or emulators (API 23 to 25 latest updates). It works fine on iOS. Actually we can hear the sound but the video does not render on the screen.

```html
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
  <video controls="controls" preload="metadata" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" />
  </video>
</ion-content>
```

I read tones of posts about similar issues but nobody seems to have a solution that works for me or uses different technologies. Among the solution I've tried are:

- Made sure hardwareAccelerated is set to true in the Android manifest.
- Added overflow-scroll="true" to the <ion-content> section.
- Removed type="video/mp4" to the video source tag.
- Made sure the mp4 file uses supported encoding (H.264)
- Tried different ionic/cordova CLI and Core versions
- Updated Android SDKs

Yesterday I was fortunate enough to find out that enabling the multi-process WebView in Settings / Dev Tools on a device makes the video work again but it's not an option for our clients. So it has something to do with WebView and the latest Android updates (October) but I don't know what and definitely don't know how to fix it.

Here is the code I use: [Ionic Video Problem / StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-video-android)

But like I said, it works fine in a browser, you have to download, compile et send it to an Android device to see the problem.

I've been struggling with that for a week. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post your code in https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-video-android

Comment: Checked your and i just copy home.html and home.ts file everything works fine

Comment: Have you built and deployed to an android device? That's where the problem shows. The emulator also has the problem.

Comment: No checked in real device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this probably was a manufacturer issue as it disappeared for most of our users recently after applying a particular update. The problem showed on Samsung S7 running Android 7.0. Before the update we could temporary fix the bug by enabling Multi-process WebView in the settings as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have had issues with this on Android if they have not installed [crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview).

This helps make your Chrome version compatible across a wide variety of Android versions and devices.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
  <video controls="controls" preload="metadata" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" />
  </video>
</ion-content>
```